# JPA: How to handle multiple Entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm new to JPA and have a question about how to handle entitites. In my case I have 3 Entities: User, Group and Event.

An event always belongs to a group. Which means there is a OneToMany-Relation. A user can subscribe to multiple groups which means there is a ManyToMany-Relation. Now the part where I'm having troubles. A user can also subscribe to multiple events which means that there is also a ManyToMany-Relation.

[image]
As code:

### User

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Embedded
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_location")
    private CompanyLocation companyLocation;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_group_subscriptions",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Group> subscribedGroups;
    ...
}
```

### Group

```
@Entity
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(???)
    private List<Event> events;
    ...
}
```

Now my problem. How can I have a list with susbcribed events in my Group-Entity which depends on the User-Entity?
My goal would be something like this:

```
user.getSubscribedGroups().get(0).getSubscribedEvents();
```

Comment: Group-Event relation should be Many-to-Many as many groups can subscribe to many events and that subscriptions can overlap. Do it via join table just like you did with `User#subscribedGroup` Both One2Many and ManyToMany can be done with join tables.

Comment: @Antoniossss but this would mean that an Event can have multiple Groups which should not be possible

Comment: I dont know the details, but for example admins and moderators should be able to subscribe to eg. System shutdown event - one event multiple groups. I guess that my concept of group is different but that does not matter here. One2Many can be done with `@JoinTable`

Comment: As for the diagram you shown, event can have multiple groups - so your relation is different. If single event can have **ONLY ONE GROUP** then the relation should be 1-1

Comment: And now I started to think that you want reverse relation. Event can have only one group, but group can have multiple events. So I guess the relation should be 1 group many events.

Comment: @Antoniossss oh looks like i did a mistake there...but my main question is still how i can perform a jointable with attributes (User#id) that the Group-Entity don't has? Normaly i would join the User#id and Event#id like i did it in Group but the join takes place in the Group-Entity and not the User-Entity

Comment: I dont understand. What you want to do is to fetch User->Group->Events. This is doable with simple mapping that you almous hav. I dont know what is causing you the troubles here. Either use additional join table to map Group-Events (like you did for user-group but with @OneToMany), or place group id in Event.

Comment: oh god i'm really stupid...now I get it what you meant..Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
@Entity
public class Event{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "your_column")
private Group group;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(....)
private List<User> users;

...

}

@Entity
public class Group {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Event> events;

...
}
```